# Auto arrange 4 window on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys

I know that there is a key combination to auto arrange 2 windows (one to the left, one to the right) on Windows 7: <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>right/left arrow</kbd>

Is there any hot-key for 4 windows? I mean one to left-up side, one to left-down, etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont know about the key but what you can do is open all the documents you want to display side to side then on the clock on taskbar right click from pop-up menu click show windows side by side automatically all the four windows will be shown side by side all at once